# Jquery datepicker failed to set min\max date if it try to trigger button click during onClose

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui, webforms, .net-4.0

`$("#txtCreateTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);` failed to function if `$("#btnFilter").trigger('click');` is called after it.

`$("#btnFilter").trigger('click');` is link to code behind.

```
protected void btnFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridViewTransactionInfo.DataBind();
}
```

It's working when I commented\disable `$("#btnFilter").trigger('click');`.

How can I set min\max date before I trigger click of `btnFilter`?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtCreateFrom").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            showWeek: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#txtCreateTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                $("#btnFilter").trigger('click');
            },
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            altField: "#txtCreateFromAlternate",
            altFormat: "dd M, yy",
            onSelect: function () {

            }
        });
        $("#txtCreateTo").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            showWeek: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#txtCreateFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
                $("#btnFilter").trigger('click');
            },
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            altField: "#txtCreateToAlternate",
            altFormat: "dd M, yy",
            onSelect: function () {

            }
        });
        $('#txtCreateFromAlternate').attr('readonly', true);
        $('#txtCreateToAlternate').attr('readonly', true);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i basically copied your code it was able to set the min and max values. Can you post the console error?

Comment: @AlexW copied my code to? visual studio? jsfiddle? my is visual studio 2015.

Comment: your error was js related right, i don't need your backend C# code to replicate your problem. Or am i missing something. Its my understanding that the line of code failing is the code to set the min and max dates, is that not correct?

Comment: @AlexW I tested on jsfiddle and it works too, not when I tested it in visual studio with the C# code behind.

Comment: right, I assume your click function would trigger a post back, therefore losing your min and max values set. There is a couple of ways you can resolve this. You can either use an api call get get the data for `gridViewTransactionInfo` and set it client side or server side, if you are using mvc, add two additional fields to your view model for min and max date